# In app purchase Cancelled and refunded callbacks not invoked

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

We are trying to incorporate in app purchase and we are not getting proper callbacks.

```
Cancelled
Refunded
```

Overview: We are developing in app purchase in our hybrid application using IONIC. We have incorporated the plugin for In App Purchase:

• Device version iPhone 6s Plus
• iOS version : iOS 15.5

Steps:
Registered In app subscriptions on App Store Connect
In mobile app I
Call OS ready function

```
    Register the Product
    this.store.register({
    id: this.PRODUCT_IOS_MONTHLY_RECURRING_ID,
    type: this.store.NON_CONSUMABLE
    });

    Register the callbacks
    this.store.when(this.PRODUCT_IOS_MONTHLY_RECURRING_ID)
    .cancelled(this.purchaseCancelled)
    .updated(this.purchaseMonthlyUpdated)
    .approved(this.purchaseApproved)
    .verified(this.purchaseVerified)
    .refunded(this.purchaseRefunded)
    .owned(this.purchaseOwned);

    Call Refresh
```

Now after this I am getting the data for this Product and I can call purchase.

{"id":"2022-06-21T04:42:53.592Z","value":"updated { id : 1MonthRecurring , alias : 1MonthRecurring , type : non consumable , group : 20959546 , state : registered , title : 1-Month Recurring Subscription , description : Monthly Recurring Subscription , priceMicros :9990000, price : $9.99 , currency : USD , countryCode : US , loaded :false, canPurchase :false, owned :false, introPrice :null, introPriceMicros :null, introPricePeriod :null, introPricePeriodUnit :null, introPricePaymentMode :null, ineligibleForIntroPrice :null, discounts :[], downloading :false, downloaded :false, additionalData :null, transaction :null, billingPeriod :1, billingPeriodUnit : Month }"}

After purchase it gives me owned state.

{"id":"2022-06-21T04:42:57.198Z","value":"updated { id : 1MonthRecurring , alias : 1MonthRecurring , type : non consumable , group : 20959546 , state : owned , title : 1-Month Recurring Subscription , description : Monthly Recurring Subscription , priceMicros :9990000, price : $9.99 , currency : USD , countryCode : US , loaded :true, canPurchase :false, owned :true, introPrice :null, introPriceMicros :null, introPricePeriod :null, introPricePeriodUnit :null, introPricePaymentMode :null, ineligibleForIntroPrice :null, discounts :[], downloading :false, downloaded :false, additionalData :null, transaction :{ type : ios-appstore , id : 2000000084829744 , appStoreReceipt :
....

Now when I go to settings and sandbox account and cancel subscription I am not getting the cancelled callback.

Also I should get the refund callback. Although in settings screen I see that the subscription is not in owned state still the application shows OWNED.

I would want to know how can I get the cancelled and refunded callbacks

Answer (score 2):

cancelled callback is sent to your server not on device. You need to implement [App Store Server Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications) for that.